# How do i print multiple variables in separate lines into a file using shell scripting

Tags: shell, csv

i need to select string from one csv file to another properties file using shell

project.csv - this is the file which contains data like below & this may contain N number of lines/data

```
PN549,projects.pn549
SaturnTV_SW,projects.saturntv_sw
```

Need to collect each string "pn549" , "saturntv_sw" into a properties file

properties

```
[projects]
pn549_pt=pn549
saturntv_sw_pt=saturntv_sw
```

Below is the code i wrote to fetch the string and to print

```
cat "project.csv" | while IFS='' read -r line; do
Display_Name="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d '"')"
project_name="$(echo "$TEMP_Name" | cut -d '.' -f 2)"
echo "$project_name"
echo "$project_name"_pt="$project_name" > /opt/properties
```

How do i print multiple lines like i gave in example(properties)

Comment: @here guys could anyone help me out?\

Comment: `printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"` or `echo -e "$var1\n$var2\n$var3"`

Comment: What's the actual rule for the modification here? You just want to pick the part after the dot and print that? Where does `project_name` come from?

Comment: If you have a block of text you want to *redirect* to a file, use a *heredoc*, e.g. `cat << EOF >filename $var_on_line_1 Some other text $var_on_line_2 other stuff $var_on_line_3 then next line is EOF`

Comment: @ilkkachu there is no modification, i just simply need to create properties file using project.csv. Sorry for the confusion "project_name" & "$URL_Name" are same. i have edit it back in the question

Comment: @SubratSahoo, I meant the rules for generating the expected output from the given input. You're still not setting `project_name` anywhere in the script.

Comment: @ilkkachu ass i have mentioned, sorry for the blunder in the code snippet.
i have cleared it now

Answer (score 1):

i have got my answer, simply redirected the output